# Naming predicates for plural objects

Tags: naming-conventions, predicate

I have a model "messages". And it should have a predicate, which will indicate, are they (messages) fetching. Should I name it "areFetching" or "isFetching"?

I tried to google "predicates naming conventions", but they all are only about "is" and "has" prefixes.